# Bulletproof approach to tackle SQL transaction timeouts

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transactions

Recently we faced quite an interesting issue that has to do with SQL transactions timeout. The statement that timed out does not really matter for the sake of question, but it was single INSERT statement w/o explicit transaction with client generated GUID as a key:

```
INSERT MyTable
(id, ...)
VALUES (<client-app-generated-guid>, ...)
```

We also have a retry policies in-place, so that if command fails with SqlException, then it will be retried. SQL Server (Azure SQL) did not behave normally one day and we faced a lot of strange PK violation errors during retries. They were caused by *retrying* actually successfully *committed* on the SQL Server transaction (so that causes insert with already taken ID). I understand that SQL timeout it's [purely client side concept](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/khen1234/2005/10/20/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-query-timeout/), so if Client thinks that SqlCommand failed - it *might or might not* mean it.

I suspect that Client explicit transaction control via for instance wrapping statements with `TransactionScope` as shown bellow will fix 99% of such troubles -- because Commit is actually quite fast&cheap operation. However, I still see the caveat there -- the timeout also can happen on Committing stage. The application again can be in conditions where it's impossible to guess whether transaction really committed or not (to figure out necessity of retry).

The question is how to write code in bulletproof (to such kind of troubles) and **generic** fashion and do a retry only when it's positively clear that transaction was not committed.

```
using (var trx = new TransactionScope())
using (var con = GetOpenConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Execute("<some-non-idempotent-query>");

    // what if Complete() times out?!
    // to retry or not to retry?!
    trx.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Even if the framework code did have some 99% way of reporting a committed transaction, if you were quick, you could still pull the plug before the client got the confirmation from SQL Server that the COMMIT TRAN had actually been executed successfully. I think this may be more of a problem on SQL Azure and less of a problem for on-premesis just because of the SLA/Latency of the SQL Azure call.

There isn't a way of telling if your commit succeeded. Even a read-after-write might simply pick up someone elses changes in a high volume environment.

Comment: @PhillipH, thanks! How to overcome such issues then?

Comment: If your commit fails, in the retry handling logic you may want to do a conditional re-insert, as in `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE id = @id)`

Comment: Cant you just act depending on the error? If that is timeout - retry. If that is permanent error (like PK violation) - dont. Similar to how SMTP has permanent and transient errors.

Comment: Can you convert these tables to SQL Azure temporal tables, you then have full access to change history. For inserts you can use the approach suggested by Alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Exception does not mean that the transaction failed. For any compensating action (like retrying) you need to have a definite way of telling if it failed. There are scalability issues with what I will suggest, but its the technique that is the important thing, the scalability issues can be solved in other ways.

My solution;

1. the last INSERT before COMMIT is to write a Guid to a tracking table.
2. if an exception occurs, that indicates a network failure, SELECT @@TRANCOUNT. If it indicates you are still in a transaction (is greater than 0)(which probably should never happen, but its worth checking) then you can happily resubmit your COMMIT
3. If @@TRANCOUNT returns 0 then you are no longer in a transaction. Selecting your Guid from the tracking table will tell you whether your COMMIT was successful.
4. If your commit was not successful (@@TRANCOUNT ==0 and your Guid is not present in the tracking table) then resubmit your entire batch from the BEGIN TRANSACTION onwards.

Comment: Thanks! What about something more generic? Can we come up with an approach that will work for arbitrary non-idempotent code?

Comment: The general pattern in my example will technically work for all SQL batches. However; all SQL batches generally depend on the state of the database they find within their transaction batch (and the prior state found in preparation of the batch), and once you lose your connection you cannot guarantee that the batch logic will repeat identically. You might need to build in some kind of compensation scheme for each business process - just repeating the batch might be inappropriate. Consider that the compensation is as important as the code that builds the transaction in the first place.

Comment: How to translate such suggestion if the transaction is like "update accounts set balance = balance + 100 where id = 123"?

Comment: Whats wrong with just resubmitting your indicated SQL batch if it meets condition (4) above ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I just did not get you point correctly: I thought the "tracking table" you are referring to was the table that I'm going to write "master" data to. Now I see that you are talking about special meta-table just to track to transactions. Thank you! (that match ups with second answer provided by Vladimir Baranov pretty much)

Answer (score 3):

The general approach is: try to read back what you just tried to insert.

If you can read back the ID that you tried to insert, then previous transaction committed successfully, no need to retry.

If you can't find the ID that you tried to insert, then you know that your attempt to insert has failed, so you should retry.

---

I'm afraid there is no way to have a completely generic pattern that would work for any SQL statement. Your "checking" code needs to know what to look for.

If it is `INSERT` with ID - then you are looking for that ID.

If it is some `UPDATE`, then the check would be custom and depend on the nature of that `UPDATE`.

If it is `DELETE`, then the check consists of trying to read what was meant to be deleted.

---

Actually, here is a generic pattern: any data modification batch that has one or multiple `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements should have one more `INSERT` statement within that transaction that inserts some GUID (some ID of the data modifying transaction itself) into a dedicated audit table. Then your checking code tries to read that same GUID from that dedicated audit table. If GUID is found, then you know that previous transaction committed successfully. If GUID is not found, then you know that previous transaction was rolled back and you can retry.

Having this dedicated audit table unifies/standardize the checks. The checks no longer depend on internals and details of your data changing code. Your data modification code and verification code depend on the same agreed interface - audit table.

Comment: This third section is exactly what I had in my mind too! Thanks for exposing that. Let's wait for other responses anyway.

Comment: I've marked PhillipH's answer as a solution - it's the same as your suggestion in a nutshell, but he just answered first. Thank you again, Vladimir!